# Avoid the iteration of tile in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a tile to show in react-native-maps. The tile loaded successfully and shows perfectly. Because the tile is not a geographical map, I don't want to have a loop in the map. Currently if user scroll to left or right, he will see the tile again and again. I need just to show one single rendered tile there. Here is the code:

```
 <MapView
                onRegionChangeStart={() => setIsZooming(true)}
                onRegionChangeComplete={() => setIsZooming(false)}
                provider={'google'} // Prevents map tiles from loading
                maximumZ={19}
                mapType={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'none' : 'standard'}
                minimumZ={2}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                showsUserLocation={false} // Hide user location marker
                customMapStyle={customMapStyle} // Apply the custom map style here
                style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
                <UrlTile
                  /**
                   * The url template of the tile server. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be replaced at runtime
                   * For example, http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
                   */
                  urlTemplate={TILE_URL}
                  zIndex={-1000}
                  /**
                   * The maximum zoom level for this tile overlay. Corresponds to the maximumZ setting in
                   * MKTileOverlay. iOS only.
                   */
                  shouldReplaceMapContent={true}
                  flipY={false}
                  /**
                   * flipY allows tiles with inverted y coordinates (origin at bottom left of map)
                   * to be used. Its default value is false.
                   */
                />
                {/* Render your markers */}
                {showPositionMarker.map(marker => (
                  <Marker
                    key={marker.id}
                    coordinate={{
                      latitude: marker.position.lat,
                      longitude: marker.position.lng,
                    }}
                  />
                ))}
              </MapView>
            </View>
```

Can you help me to fix it?